# I need a way to use analog electronic components to invert an irregular wave

Tags: analog, wave, information

I am doing a personal project wherein I am using an EMG sensor on my muscles, amplifying the output, and then running it to a lead on a motor. What I can't figure out is how to invert the irregular wave in a way that they would add to cancel each other. The two opposite waves would run to the two leads on a motor so the electricity running to the motor is proportional to the output of the EMG sensor. I haven't tried anything yet as I would like to get the information before I start ordering components.

Comment: I don't get why you need to cancel your signal. If you're producing a useful signal with EMG, you want to produce another signal with the opposite sign to add them and get 0?

Comment: looks like an XY question ... asking for help with what you consider to be a solution to an unspecified problem, even if the solution may be misguided ... instead, please ask about the actual problem that you are trying to solve

Comment: I think they might be under the impression that the "-" terminal of the motor needs an inverted version of the voltage at the "+" terminal.

Comment: Please share a picture of your circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way something like this is traditionally done is to use two amplifiers. There are a couple of different ways of doing it.

1. The input signal is fed into both an inverting and a non-inverting amplifier, both with the same gain, with the outputs of the amplifiers providing signals 180\$^\circ\$ out of phase.
2. The input signal is fed into a non-inverting amplifier, the output of which is attenuated by the same amount as it's gain and then fed to the input of an inverting amplifier with the same gain.
3. The same as #2, but both amplifiers are inverting.

In audio amplifiers this is know as a Bridge Tied Load (BTL) amplifier and is used because it can effectively double the voltage to the load.

You can see some examples of this in [this article](https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/optimizing-audio-bridged-tied-load-amplifiers.html). Figure 1 is an example of the one I have as #3, figure two is #1.

There's also a fourth way, which isn't used very much anymore, and that is to use an amplifier driving a transformer. The problem with this is the size, expense and limited frequency response of the transformer.

Comment: This was exactly the information I was looking for! Thank you internet stranger your information is useful in my applications.